# Explanation to java code

Tags: java

I know the answer to this question, but do not understand the logic.

I am looking for an explanation as to how the final values equal `i=1951, j=0`

```
int i = 60;
int j = 50;
int count = 0;
while (count < 5)
{
   i = i + i;
   i = i + 1;
   j = j - 1;
   j = j - j;
   count++;
}
System.out.println("i=" + i + ", j=" + j);
```

Comment: Do a dry-run by yourself. It's easy

Comment: Which part is giving you trouble?  If you got a different result, how did you arrive at it?

Comment: The loop body runs 5 times. Get some pencil and paper and record the value of i and j at the end of each loop.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's the height of laziness.

Comment: Learn basic debugging: insert a print statement *within* the loop, anywhere you don't understand the process.  Examine the progression of values displayed.

Comment: Thanks @Prune.  I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple explanation to your question :

Let's dry-run this while loop:

```
count = 0 i.e. (count<5): 
i = i + i -> i = 60 + 60 = 120;
i = i + 1 -> i = 120 + 1 = 121;
j = j - 1 -> j = 50 - 1 = 49;
j = j - j -> j = 49 - 49 = 0;
count = count ++ -> count= 0 + 1 = 1;

count = 1 i.e. (count<5): 
i = i + i -> i = 121 + 121 = 242;
i = i + 1 -> i = 242 + 1 = 243;
j = j - 1 -> j = 0 - 1 = -1;
j = j - j -> j = -1 - (-1) = 0;
count = count ++ -> count= 1 + 1 = 2;

count = 2 i.e. (count<5): 
i = i + i -> i = 243 + 243 = 486;
i = i + 1 -> i = 486 + 1 = 487;
j = j - 1 -> j = 0 - 1 = -1;
j = j - j -> j = -1 - (-1) = 0;
count = count ++ -> count= 2 + 1 = 3;

count = 3 i.e. (count<5): 
i = i + i -> i = 487 + 487 = 974;
i = i + 1 -> i = 974 + 1 = 975;
j = j - 1 -> j = 0 - 1 = -1;
j = j - j -> j = -1 - (-1) = 0;
count = count ++ -> count= 3 + 1 = 4;

count = 4 i.e. (count<5): 
i = i + i -> i = 974 + 974 = 1950;
i = i + 1 -> i = 1950 + 1 = 975;
j = j - 1 -> j = 0 - 1 = -1;
j = j - j -> j = -1 - (-1) = 0;
count = count ++ -> count= 4 + 1 = 5;
```

Loop breaks now as count = 5.

Final values will now be i=1951 and j=0;

Answer (score 1):

Please - this is simple to work out for yourself.  Put in some effort.

```
count     i     j
0         121   0
1         243   0
2         487   0
3         975   0
4         1951  0
```

Printing out the line-by-line results would make it clear enough.  After that it's just addition and subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop body can be rewrite as follows:

`i = 2*i + 1 ;`

`j = 0 ;`

You have made the loop body complex unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

**j = 0**

This is fairly obvious since the last operation in the loop is `j = j - j`, so `j` will always be 0 after that no matter the input.

**i = 1951**

In the loop you do `i = i + i` and then `i = i + 1`, so after these operations the new i is `2i + 1`. You execute the loop 5 times so you compute `2(2(2(2(2i+1)+1)+1)+1)+1` and a bit of simple math will tell you that this is 1951 if i was 60 initially.